# Trouble with SQL query

Tags: java, database, sqlite, jdbc, parameter-passing

I'm new in database and sql, and just trying to figure it all out in Java, but I got stuck with some minor problem, I'm trying to remove one record in db, with id that is given as method parameter, like this, but it's not working

```
@Override
public void removeCustomer(int number) {
    Statement statement = null;
    try {
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM Customers WHERE id='number'");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try{
            if(statement != null) statement.close();
        } catch (SQLException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

It does work, when I write in SQL query " ... WHERE id='2'";
But I want to be able to pass the number from method parameter. 
Anyone could help?

Comment: Can you please provide the stacktrace?

Comment: Please [learn to use a `PreparedStatement`](https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-delete-a-record/)

Comment: Java doesn't have string interpolation (and if it did, this would be susceptible to SQL injection).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**PreparedStatement**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) like so :

```
try(PreparedStatement stm = connection.createStatement("DELETE FROM Customers WHERE id=?")){
    stm.setInt(1, number);
    stm.executeUpdate();
}
//.. catch and finally
```

---

**Note**

> It does work, when I write in SQL query " ... WHERE id='2'";

If in case your id is a `varchar` you can pass a string to the statement by using `setString` instead of `setInt`, but I don't suggest to use string for `id`

Comment: No, my id is regular and typical int, nonetheless it did work with id=2, and id='2' ->it's not a bug it's a feature ;)